# AWS Amplify - com.amplifyframework.AmplifyException: Unknown/bad category type: dataStore

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

Good day All,

I have this error during data store plugin adding on amplify initialization.

`com.amplifyframework.AmplifyException: Unknown/bad category type: dataStore`

I have added the code i believe is pertinent, please ask for more if need it, have follow documentation as good as possible.

Thanks !!

Android logs

```
2020-04-17 18:58:55.797 30894-30928/com.bakeano.htejobs E/bakeanoMessage: Amplify adding plugins Exception: Unknown/bad category type: dataStore
    com.amplifyframework.AmplifyException: Unknown/bad category type: dataStore
        at com.amplifyframework.core.AmplifyConfiguration.forCategoryType(AmplifyConfiguration.java:4)
        at com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify.configure(Amplify.java:16)
        at com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify.configure(Amplify.java:1)
        at com.bakeano.htejobs.MyApplication$1.onResult(MyApplication.java:36)
        at com.bakeano.htejobs.MyApplication$1.onResult(MyApplication.java:23)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:75)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.onResult(InternalCallback.java:62)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$2.run(AWSMobileClient.java:596)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Android Application Class **(MyApplication.java)**

```
package com.bakeano.htejobs;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.Callback;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.UserStateDetails;
import com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AWSApiPlugin;
import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify;
import com.amplifyframework.core.model.ModelProvider;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.AWSDataStorePlugin;
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.AmplifyModelProvider;

public class MyApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // AWSMobileClient initialization
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(UserStateDetails result) {
                try {
                    // AWS Amplify datastore plugin
                    ModelProvider modelProvider = AmplifyModelProvider.getInstance();
                    Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin.forModels(modelProvider)); <--- Error line

                    // AWS Amplify api plugin
                    Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSApiPlugin());

                    // AWS Amplify configure
                    Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext()); <--- Exception line
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("bakeanoMessage", "Amplify adding plugins Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.e("bakeanoMessage", "AWSMobileClient init Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Amplify status from amplify-cli `amplify status`

```
Current Environment: dev

Category  |  Resource name    |  Operation  |   Provider plugin
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Api       | amplifyDatasource | No Change   |   awscloudformation
Auth      | someResourceName  | No Change   |   awscloudformation

GraphQL endpoint: https://somekey.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql
GraphQL API KEY: someotherkey
```

Comment: Was this in the pre-release of the library? Is this still happening? Can you file a bug against the AWS repo, if so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a stab in the dark, but is there any code in your repo which specifically references "dataStore", with the initial letter in lower case, rather than upper case? Just going off the "category type: dataStore" bit of the exception, and the fact that the initial letter is usually capitalized in the code I've written that works with DataStore.

Comment: Based on the use of `AWSMobileClient`, and the date that this question was asked, this user was using a pre-release version of the library. I think the solution here is to use any recent version.